# Managing when Python turtle checks for events

Tags: python, event-handling, turtle-graphics

I'm working on creating a Connect 4 game using Python turtle graphics. The main problem that has arisen is that when you use events like `onkey` or `onclick`, they are checked instantaneously followed by the remainder of the code. Is there a way to pause the code until an event happens, then continue on and, after looping, wait for another event to happen?

In the following code, the game gets setup and then the `play()` function is run. Within the `play()` function the program listens for `onkey()` events that allow the user to change which column it is over and drop the piece when ready. Then, it begins checking for 4 in a row either horizontally, vertically, or diagonally. It creates an error because the column lists are empty until I press the down key to drop a piece into a column of the board and append the piece to that column. I could create the columns already filled with `None`, `''`, or zeros but then I would have to change how my drop function works, as it currently bases the y value of where it is dropped to off of the number of items in the list. Is there a way to only run the check function once after each piece is dropped?

P.S. I'm relatively new to coding and this is my first time using this site. I have copy and pasted the code below:

```
import turtle
class Connect4:
  "A connect 4 game"
  def __init__(self):
    self.pen = turtle.Turtle()
    self.scr = turtle.Screen()
    self.board = Connect4Board(self.pen, self.scr)
    self.moves = 0
    self.playing = True
    self.piece = Connect4Piece(self.scr, self.board, self)

    self.setup()
    self.play()

  def setup(self):
    self.board.draw_board()

  def play(self):
    if self.moves == self.board.rows*self.board.columns:
      game_over()
    self.piece.st()
    self.piece.goto(0, self.board.board_height/2)
    while True:

      self.scr.onkey(self.piece.prev_col, 'Left')
      self.scr.onkey(self.piece.next_col, 'Right')
      self.scr.onkey(self.piece.drop, 'Down')
      self.scr.onkey(self.reset, 'r')
      self.scr.listen()
      self.check()

  "Check if there is 4 pieces in a line horizontally, vertically or diagonally"
  def check(self):
    self.check_horizontal()
    self.check_vertical()
    self.check_diagonal()

  def check_horizontal(self):
    print("Checking horizontally")
    for rows in range(self.board.rows):
      for columns in range(self.board.columns - 3):
        if self.board.squares[columns][rows] == 0:
          continue
        elif (self.board.squares[columns][rows] == self.board.squares[columns+1][rows] == self.board.squares[columns+2][rows] == self.board.squares[columns+3][rows]):
          print(self.board.squares[columns][rows].color())
          if self.board.squares[columns][rows].color() == ('red','red'):
            print("Red wins!")
          if self.board.squares[columns][rows].color() == ('black','black'):
            print("Black wins!")

  def check_vertical(self):
    print("Checking vertically")

  def check_diagonal(self):
    print("Checking diagonally")

  def reset(self):

    self.board.reset()
    self.piece.clear()

    self.moves = 0
    self.play()

  def game_over(self):
    self.pen.pu()
    self.pen.goto(0, board_height/2 + 20)
    self.pen.pd()
    self.pen.write("Black wins!", align='center', font = ('Arial', 24, 'normal'))
    self.pen.pu()
    to.goto(0, board_height/2 + 10)
    self.pen.write("Play Again?", align='center', font = ('Arial', 24, 'normal'))
    self.playing = False

class Connect4Board:
  def __init__(self, pen, screen):
      #Used to create the board
    self.square_size = 60
    self.rows = 6
    self.columns = 7
    self.pen = pen
    self.frame_color = 'blue'
    self.board_length = self.square_size*self.columns
    self.board_height = self.square_size*self.rows
    self.squares = [[] for cols in range(self.columns)] 
    """for cols in range(self.columns):
      empty = []
      self.squares.append(empty)"""

    self.pen.speed(0)
    self.pen.ht()

  def _draw_square(self, x, y):
    self.pen.pu()
    self.pen.goto(x-self.square_size/2, y-self.square_size/2)
    self.pen.pd()
    self.pen.fillcolor(self.frame_color)
    self.pen.begin_fill()
    for sides in range(4):
      self.pen.fd(self.square_size)
      self.pen.left(90)
    self.pen.end_fill()

  def _draw_circle(self, x, y):
    self.pen.pu()
    self.pen.goto(x, y)
    self.pen.pd()
    self.pen.fillcolor('white')
    self.pen.begin_fill()
    self.pen.circle(self.square_size/2)
    self.pen.end_fill()

  def draw_board(self):
    for row in range(self.rows):
      for col in range(self.columns):
        x = col*self.square_size - self.board_length/2 + self.square_size/2
        y = row*self.square_size - self.board_length/2
        self._draw_square(x, y)
        self._draw_circle(x, y - self.square_size/2)

  def reset(self):
    self.squares = []
    for cols in range(self.columns):
      empty = []
      self.squares.append(empty)

class Connect4Piece(turtle.Turtle):

  def __init__(self, screen, board, game):
    turtle.Turtle.__init__(self, screen)
    self.board = board
    self.speed(0)
    self.pu()
    self.shape('turtle')
    self.cnum = 3
    self.game = game
    self.ht()

  "Moves the piece to the left and updates it's column number"
  def prev_col(self):
    if self.xcor() - self.board.square_size > -self.board.board_length/2:
      self.setx(self.xcor() - self.board.square_size)
      self.cnum -= 1

  "Moves the piece to the right and updates it's column number"
  def next_col(self):
    if self.xcor() + self.board.square_size < self.board.board_length/2:
      self.setx(self.xcor() + self.board.square_size)
      self.cnum += 1

  def drop(self):
    "Make sure the column isn't full. If it's not then move the turtle to the next available space in the row."
    if len(self.board.squares[self.cnum]) != self.board.rows:
      self.sety(len(self.board.squares[self.cnum])              *self.board.square_size - self.board.board_height/2 - self.board.square_size/2 )

      "Stamp an image of the turtle to represent placing a piece"
      self.stamp()
      self.board.squares[self.cnum].append(self.color())

      "Move the piece back above the middle column and set it's column back to 3"
      self.goto(0, self.board.board_height/2)
      self.cnum = 3

      "Change the piece's color"
      if self.color() == ('red','red'):
        self.color('black')
      else:
        self.color('red')

      self.game.moves += 1
      print(self.game.moves, "moves")

game = Connect4()
```

Comment: Please try to make a minimal example, e.g. if you are asking about reacting to an event, make an application which does only that - reacts to only one event or two events if that is the minimum to reproduce the problem. Then ask the question, which will probably already be much simpler. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Your program is structured incorrectly, as epitomized by this loop:

```
while True:

  self.scr.onkey(self.piece.prev_col, 'Left')
  self.scr.onkey(self.piece.next_col, 'Right')
  self.scr.onkey(self.piece.drop, 'Down')
  self.scr.onkey(self.reset, 'r')
  self.scr.listen()
  self.check()
```

First, `while True:` has no place in an event-driven environment like turtle.  Second, these `onkey` calls only need to be done *once* during initialization -- they don't do anything at runtime.  (Ditto `listen()`)

I've restructured your code below to be event-based.  You need to add (back) the checking code to determine if there's a winner or not:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

class Connect4:
    "A connect 4 game"

    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.pen = Turtle()
        self.scr = screen
        self.board = Connect4Board(self.pen)
        self.moves = 0
        self.playing = False
        self.piece = Connect4Piece(self.board, self)

        self.scr.tracer(False)
        self.board.draw_board()
        self.scr.tracer(True)

        self.scr.onkey(self.piece.prev_col, 'Left')
        self.scr.onkey(self.piece.next_col, 'Right')
        self.scr.onkey(self.piece.drop, 'Down')
        self.scr.onkey(self.reset, 'r')

        self.scr.listen()

    def play(self):

        self.piece.showturtle()
        self.piece.goto(0, self.board.board_height/2)
        self.playing = True

    def check(self):
        "Check if there are 4 pieces in a line horizontally, vertically or diagonally"

        if self.moves == self.board.rows * self.board.columns:
            self.game_over()

        if self.check_horizontal():
            self.game_over()

        if self.check_vertical():
            self.game_over()

        if self.check_diagonal():
            self.game_over()

    def check_horizontal(self):
        print("Checking horizontally")

        # implement this correctly

        return False

    def check_vertical(self):
        print("Checking vertically")

        # implement this

        return False

    def check_diagonal(self):
        print("Checking diagonally")

        # implement this

        return False

    def reset(self):

        self.playing = False

        self.board.reset()
        self.piece.clear()

        self.moves = 0
        self.play()

    def game_over(self):
        self.playing = False
        self.pen.penup()
        self.pen.goto(0, self.board.board_height/2 + 20)
        self.pen.pendown()
        self.pen.write("Black wins!", align='center', font=('Arial', 24, 'normal'))
        self.pen.penup()
        self.pen.goto(0, self.board.board_height/2 + 10)
        self.pen.write("Play Again?", align='center', font=('Arial', 24, 'normal'))

class Connect4Board:
    def __init__(self, pen):
        # Used to create the board
        self.square_size = 60
        self.rows = 6
        self.columns = 7
        self.pen = pen
        self.frame_color = 'blue'
        self.board_length = self.square_size * self.columns
        self.board_height = self.square_size * self.rows
        self.squares = [[] for _ in range(self.columns)]

        self.pen.speed('fastest')
        self.pen.hideturtle()

    def _draw_square(self, x, y):
        self.pen.penup()
        self.pen.goto(x - self.square_size/2, y - self.square_size/2)
        self.pen.pendown()
        self.pen.fillcolor(self.frame_color)

        self.pen.begin_fill()
        for _ in range(4):
            self.pen.forward(self.square_size)
            self.pen.left(90)
        self.pen.end_fill()

    def _draw_circle(self, x, y):
        self.pen.penup()
        self.pen.goto(x, y)
        self.pen.pendown()
        self.pen.fillcolor('white')

        self.pen.begin_fill()
        self.pen.circle(self.square_size/2)
        self.pen.end_fill()

    def draw_board(self):
        for row in range(self.rows):
            for col in range(self.columns):
                x = col * self.square_size - self.board_length/2 + self.square_size/2
                y = row * self.square_size - self.board_length/2
                self._draw_square(x, y)
                self._draw_circle(x, y - self.square_size/2)

    def reset(self):
        self.squares = [[] for _ in range(self.columns)]

class Connect4Piece(Turtle):

    def __init__(self, board, game):
        super().__init__(shape='turtle', visible=False)
        self.board = board
        self.game = game
        self.speed('fastest')
        self.penup()
        self.cnum = 3

    def prev_col(self):
        "Moves the piece to the left and updates it's column number"

        if self.xcor() - self.board.square_size > -self.board.board_length/2:
            self.setx(self.xcor() - self.board.square_size)
            self.cnum -= 1

    def next_col(self):
        "Moves the piece to the right and updates it's column number"

        if self.xcor() + self.board.square_size < self.board.board_length/2:
            self.setx(self.xcor() + self.board.square_size)
            self.cnum += 1

    def drop(self):
        "Make sure the column isn't full. If it's not then move the turtle to the next available space in the row."

        if len(self.board.squares[self.cnum]) != self.board.rows:
            self.sety(len(self.board.squares[self.cnum]) * self.board.square_size - self.board.board_height/2 - self.board.square_size/2)

            # Stamp an image of the turtle to represent placing a piece
            self.stamp()
            self.board.squares[self.cnum].append(self.color())

            # Move the piece back above the middle column and set it's column back to 3
            self.goto(0, self.board.board_height/2)
            self.cnum = 3

            # Change the piece's color
            self.color('black' if self.pencolor() == 'red' else 'red')

            self.game.moves += 1
            print(self.game.moves, "moves")

            self.game.check()

screen = Screen()

game = Connect4(screen)
game.play()

screen.mainloop()
```

The graphics behave as expected but when you drop a turtle you'll see the stub checking functions get invoked and the player switches.

Also, read about Python comments vs. document strings -- you're mixing them up.